# why every time i open xcode project it shows to revoke code signing certificate?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

every time when i open xcode project for ios mobile app it show following message:

"Your account already has a signing certificate for this machine but it is not present in your keychain. To create a new one, you must first revoke the existing certificate."

and Every time create new certificate. it happnes after Developer account member ship is renewed.

please give me any solutions.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue on Xcode 14. I solved it without revoking. I did the following:

1. Xcode->Preferences->Accounts tab
2. Manage certificates button.
3. Click the "+" and add a cert. (I selected apple dev cert)
4. Restart Xcode.

Hope that works!

Answer (score 1):

This is saying that you have a signing certificate already but you have to put that certificate in your keychain. So if you have that certificate stored anywhere then please put that certificate in your laptop keychain. Otherwise if you dont know where is your certificate stored then you have only one option. you have to revoke(delete) the certificate from appledeveloper.com and create a new one then store it in your device keychain.

Comment: yes i did. but it says every time to revoke dont know why. is it issue of old mac version? because it is high seirra when i run that on catalina it works perfect

Comment: yeah this can be this case also is the certificate was generated by a mac higher version. but it should work fine if the certificate generated by your mac. For now you can upgrade your mac version. but keep looking for orignal reason because this versioning thing should not affect much. If my answer helped you a little bit you can upvote my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the above answer didnt help you, I think you might miss some `Apple Intermediate Certificates` in your keychain...

Go to the [Apple PKI](https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/), install the missing ones in the `Apple Intermediate Certificates` section.

Let me know if it helped

Comment: no installed all apple intermediate certificates but did not help.